# React-Router causing 12969 high severity vulnerabilities

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

Starting a new project using

```
npx create-react-app my-app --typescript
```

I had no errors, I installed

```
npm install --save react-router-dom @types/react-router-dom
```

And get the error

> mixin-deep@2.0.1 added 1 package from 1 contributor, updated 1
>   package, moved 1 package and audited 902212 packages in 13.484s found
>   12969 high severity vulnerabilities

I'm running Node v12.6.0 & npm 6.10.1 on a Windows PC.  I've tried running npm audit fix, but it states I have to fix them manually.

Installing react-router and getting 12969 high severity vulnerabilities seems a little excessive, does anyone know what's going on?  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: These errors are not caused by adding react-router-dom. Try `create-react-app` again without `react-router`, then  remove node_modules and run `npm i` - I suspect you'll see the same error. BTW this is [already reported](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7364) in create-react-app repo

Comment: Taking the steps you outlined produced 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: [So it's fixed already](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7364#issuecomment-511046951), probably

Comment: It's fixed!  Thanks for letting me know @artem